# XAML/C# Windows8 AppBar vs. outside buttons

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, windows-8, appbar

So in my application, I have a bottom app bar pop-up for various events. The problem I'm running into is that when the AppBar shows up, the other buttons lose availability. In other words, everything outside of the AppBar cannot be selected without closing the AppBar first. To select one, the user would have to click outside the AppBar and THEN select the button. This is obviously not a friendly UI, so I'm looking for a fix.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain the events you are looking to hook into are **outside events** as Microsoft stipulates in their [style guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx)?

From the guide:

> App bars provide the user with easy access to commands when they need them. The user can swipe the bottom edge of the screen to make app bars appear and can interact with their content to make app bars disappear. App bars can also be used to show commands or options that are specific to the user's context, such as photo selection or drawing mode.
>   **If you have a command that is necessary for a user to complete a workflow (such as buying a product), place those commands on the canvas instead of in app bars.**

I would be deliberate in figuring out what is *required* and put those outside your appbar, and what is *nice to have for context/outside the current workflow* and put those inside your appbar.

Comment: In my situation, the AppBar is simply giving the user more options than they originally had available on the canvas. These additional options are only needed under certain circumstances, so I don't want a permanent button on the canvas taking up space the 99% of the time it's not being used.

Ideally, I want either option (AppBar or Canvas) to have the availability to be selected in only one click.

Comment: Could you disable the app bar in this instance and then use the space gained to add the actions you need? I'm not trying to be dense here, just curious if the appbar is necessary in your case :)

Comment: I suppose this would be a potential solution, but it would throw away the continuity/consistency of my program. If I can't find another way to solve it, I'll probably do this.

Thank you for your help!